# Explanation of protocol secure under random oracle but insecure with any hash function

Tags: random-oracle-model

It is known that there is a protocol that is secure in the random oracle model, but where any real hash function makes the protocol insecure.  The proof is constructive, but I could not understand the protocol in question.

Could someone explain the protocol in language that is easier for a programmer to understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the "simple" examples are of the form

> adversary can send honest party arbitrarily-long messages
>
> messages sent by honest parties in that context all start with 0
>
> when an honest party receives a message in that context that starts with 1, if the rest of that message encodes a [circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_circuit) then:
>
> - The honest party evaluates that circuit and the oracle at a secret value.
> - If the outputs are equal then the honest party does something obviously insecure.

[This paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2003/034) shows that even Fiat-Shamir can fail.

Comment: I can't parse this sentence *"when an honest party receives a message in that context that starts with 1, if the rest of it encodes a circuit then..."*