# Random oracle vs implementations like hash function

Tags: hash, random-oracle-model

In [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/880/32536), it is stated

> It has actually been shown (by Canetti, Goldreich and Halevi) that
> random oracles cannot exist "in all generality" in the following
> sense: it is possible to build pathological signature and asymmetric
> encryption schemes, which are secure when they internally use a random
> oracle, but which are insecure whenever an actual computable function
> is used instead of the mythical gnome-in-the-box.

I tried reading the actual paper but I am quite lost. Is there some intuition/simple example that one can provide for a cryptographic task that is secure if random oracles exist but fails when one uses a computable function instead of the random oracle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32978/explanation-of-protocol-secure-under-random-oracle-but-insecure-with-any-hash-fu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also not been satisfied with the "classic" counterexamples of random oracle instantiability. I came up with the following for the upcoming version of my book, and am happy to give a sneak preview here.

Consider the following symmetric-key encryption scheme, parameterized by hash function $H : \{0,1\}^\lambda \to \{0,1\}^\lambda$:

> $\textsf{Enc}(K,M)$:
>
> - $R \gets \{0,1\}^\lambda$
> - interpreting $M$ as the encoding of a boolean circuit, test whether $M(R) = H(R)$
>
>   - if so, set $S = K$
>   - else, set $S \gets \{0,1\}^\lambda$
> - encrypt $M$ under CBC mode using $S$ as the IV; output the result.

You can show the following about this encryption scheme:

- If $H$ is modeled as a random oracle, then the construction is CPA-secure. With overwhelming probability, $\textsf{Enc}$ chooses an $R$ that no one has ever queried to the random oracle, so $H(R)$ is independent of whatever $M(R)$ is. With overwhelming probability, $\textsf{Enc}$ behaves just like random-IV CBC mode, which is CPA-secure.
- If $H$ is any public, efficiently computable function, then the construction is **not** CPA-secure (not even one-time secure). The attack is obvious: ask for an encryption where the plaintext is a boolean circuit that implements $H$. The resulting ciphertext will contain the encryption scheme's key.